# Javascript Find matching array based on given ids

Tags: javascript

I have these 2 array how can i write a function that will return me the arrays which match with given ids ?

```
 let data = [
    ['id 1', 'item 1', 'item 1.2'],
    ['id 2', 'item 2', 'item 2.2'],
    ['id 3', 'item 3', 'item 3.2'],
    ]

    let ids = ['id 2', 'id 3']

    find(ids, data) 
    // should return [ ['id 2', 'item 2', 'item 2.2'],  ['id 3', 'item 3', 'item 3.2']]
```

Comment: Hi, can you post some more code of things you've tried? E.g. how have you tried to implement `find(ids, data)`? From that we can help point out any missteps along the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're checking the `ids` agains the **first** index of the nested `data` array, you can use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) combined with [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) like so:

```js
let data = [ ['id 1', 'item 1', 'item 1.2'], ['id 2', 'item 2', 'item 2.2'], ['id 3', 'item 3', 'item 3.2'] ];
let ids = ['id 2', 'id 3']

let res = data.filter((d) => ids.includes(d[0]));
console.log(res);
```

```json
[
  [
    "id 2",
    "item 2",
    "item 2.2"
  ],
  [
    "id 3",
    "item 3",
    "item 3.2"
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are more then one way to do, you can use [filter()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp)

```
let data = [
    ['id 1', 'item 1', 'item 1.2'],
    ['id 2', 'item 2', 'item 2.2'],
    ['id 3', 'item 3', 'item 3.2'],
 ]

let ids = ['id 2', 'id 3']
let dataFilter=data.filter(id => ids.indexOf(id[0])  > -1 )

console.log(dataFilter);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ogtf2Lwm/